# Order Array using rsort()

Tags: php, sorting

I have the following code because I want to sort an array by the field chat_timestamp:

[image]

My php code is next, but it seems not working:

```
    function compare($a, $b)
    {
        return strnatcmp($a["chat_timestamp"], $b["chat_timestamp"]);
    }

    rsort($return, "compare");
```

How I should do that. As I see is an Array of arrays but I do not know how to handle that.

Comment: Use [usort](http://us1.php.net/usort) instead of `ksort`

Comment: It works but I want to sort by Descendent Timestamp. Is there any function that helps me?

Comment: Just change your arguments order in `strnatcmp` inside callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `rsort` but should use `usort` instead of it.

Second param of `rsort` is `sort_flags` and `usort` use `callback function`.

Comment: usort is working now. But I want to sort by Descendent Timestamp. Is there any function that helps me?

Comment: change the order of arguments :) `strnatcmp($b["chat_timestamp"], $a["chat_timestamp"]);`